# Dual References to IXMLSerializable

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class that implements IXMLSerializable in a .NET Standard Library, but I can't compile the library because it's referencing IXMLSerializable in two places. The output is as follows:

> error CS0433: The type 'IXmlSerializable' exists in both
>   'System.Xml.ReaderWriter, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'System.Xml.XmlSerializer,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

I only see one reference under the dependencies though (System.Xml.XmlSerializer), which I need for the XML attributes. This is my first crack at a .Net Standard Library, so is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try upgrading your reference to System.Xml.XmlSerializer to version 4.1.0.0.
The error message says that you have two references to the library, but are using different versions.  System.Xml.ReaderWriter is using a newer version than your project is, so you need to get that version.

You could also try removing your reference to System.Xml.XmlSerializer or switching it to an older version.

Comment: I'm not sure how I'd update it. If I remove the reference, then I don't have access to the [XMLAnyElement] or [XMLElement(ElementName = "---")] attributes. It feels like a catch 22...

Comment: Ok, I figured out how to upgrade it. I have to add it as a nuget package instead of an assembly reference, and now the library builds.